# RegexKitLite match?

Tags: iphone, regexkitlite

i want to replace the string aaaa{\"type\":\"video\",\"title\":\"a\",manyothershere\"}ssss to
aaaa[video]ssss

this means the string {"type":"video","title":"a",balabala"} to [video]

i use RegexKitLite,i tried the code below ,but it doesn't work.

```
    NSString *videoRegexString = @"{\"type\":\"video\",.+\"}";

NSString *replacedStr = [@"aaaa{\"type\":\"video\",\"title\":\"sdf\",manyothershere\"}ssss" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:videoRegexString withString:@"[video]"];
```

i suppose the replacedStr is "aaaa[video]ssss"  but it's nil
am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try `NSString *videoRegexString = @"{\"type\":\"video\",.+?\"}";` (Note the question mark) the `.+` may be consuming the `\"}`